# running external commands with control over the input/output in jython 2.1

Tags: python, jakarta-ee, jython

I have an application using jython2.1 and I need to run external applications, (lets say some .exe for now). I also need to capture the input and output such as logs from that program.

Jython 2.1 seems to not have the support for popen().

ANy idea how I do that , apart from depending on standard Java libraries? Just trying to explore different ways of doing that. Any small suggestion would be of great help for me Guys!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use Java's classes that do this.

```
from java.lang import Runtime
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls -l")
output = process.getInputStream() # process' output is our input
# read output somehow, while the process is generating it
```

Comment: I tried this one, and it works perfect for me. Except for the fact like if I run say Notepad.exe, the process opens the notepad but never closes until I close notepad. Is there anyway that I can get the control from the child program when it successfully ran?

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you're using jython 2.1? I mean, it's ancient - it was released 10 years ago - you can't even find download/documentation for it anymore.

10 years is a long time in software development.

Newest version seems to support the [`subprocess` module](http://www.jython.org/docs/library/subprocess.html), which is the current python way of executing a subprocess and capturing output.